# Is the preview of Android Studio well scaled?

Tags: android, android-studio, preview, genymotion

I'm making an app using Android Studio as my IDE and Genymotion as my emulator and I see a difference between the preview of Android Studio and the real output of Genymotion but I wonder which one trust.

Both of them are using a 768 x 1280 phone but it seems the one in Genymotion is bigger.

[image]

[image]

Comment: emulator and preview have different dpi settings (mdpi vs. xhdpi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dpi settings in both are different.

Android Studio is xhdpi. Genymotion is 160 dpi which mdpi (default). In order to properly compare, you'll have to set both the same pixel density and screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite hard to answer, but from **my experience**, the **default** (i never use Genymotion) emulator is better than the Android Studio's (sometimes i got lazy to use the real device). To cross-check things, you may want to try to run your apps on the default emulator and see the result.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer